# Getting Internal Server Error while sending POST Request through Ajax in Django

Tags: django, ajax

When sending Cart data through Ajax on the project details page on Add to cart button.

Error show on Console Log , Error { POST http://localhost:8000/cart/add/ 500 (Internal Server Error) }

[Error Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPmv2.png)

Urls.py:

```
path('add/', cart_add, name='cart-add')
```

Views.py:

```
def cart_add(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == "POST":
        print("oky")
        product_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        product_quantity = int(request.POST.get('product_quantity'))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

        cart.add(product=product, quantity=product_quantity)
        
        response = JsonResponse({"Prodct Name":product.name,"product Qantity":product_quantity})
        return response
```

Ajax in HTML File:

```
<script>

$(document).on('click','#add-button',function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('{{csrf_token}}')
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url : '{% url "cart-add" %}',

            data:{
                product_id: $('#add-button').val(),
                product_quantity: $('#select option:selected').text(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken : '{{csrf_token}}',
                action : 'post'

            },

            success:function(json){
                console.log(json)
            },

            error:function(xhr,errmsg,err){
                

            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What does the expanded error response show in the console? Also, the request is using "/cart/add/" but the `urls.py` just has "add/", do you have a parent `urls.py` for cart?

Comment: path('cart/', include('cart.urls')) on the main path. Error response image attached on Question details Section.

Comment: A 500 internal server error could happen when something goes wrong in your server, that is the python code of your view.  My guess without seeing more of your code (like the HTML template where you have the form) is with the `int()` function; like `product_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))`.  If, for example, `request.POST.get('product_id')` can not be converted to an `int`, an error will occur.

Comment: No , Show the same problem.... I remove the int() from code but not sloved.

Comment: Do `print(request.POST)` to see if what you are expecting is what you ate getting.

Comment: See this link as to how to send a CSRF TOKEN in an ajax call: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094062/jquery-ajax-beforesend-csrf-protection